# Can't modify my SwiftyJSON object

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I have the variable

```
    static var DeliveryStatus: [String : JSON] =
    [
        "claimable": [],
        "onTime": [],
        "future": [],
        "claimDone": [],
        "tooOld": [],
    ]
```

In my fonction I try to append some data to claimable -> Json without success
He told me it's an immutable value I don't understand why. 
Here the code where I try to change my value

```
static func moreCard(status:String, newJson: JSON)
{
    var json:JSON = JSON(DashboardManager.DeliveryStatus)
    for elem in newJson["cards"]
    {
        DeliveryStatus[status]?["cards"].array?.append(elem.1)
    }        
}
```

Comment: You are discouraged from (mis)using `SwiftyJSON` as a collection type. Use a custom struct or native `Array` / `Dictionary`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback i will edit my question

Comment: Why are all these `static` vars and methods?  Is there a reason they aren't just instance vars and methods?

Comment: Yes, I need them `static`